# Incomplete variable in ExpressJs view

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Ok, I am newbie at Nodejs and just playing with it. I was trying to convert some of my simple python codes to js. Where i am sending a get request to Youtube API and API returns 50 results in json format. 
My express setup is brand new. With ejs,stylus and no session.
Here is my index.js code

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
    var https = require("https");
    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&chart=mostPopular&key={API_KEU}&q=victorious&maxResults=50";
    https.get(url,function(response){
        response.on('data',function(d){
                response.setEncoding('utf8');
                console.log(d);
                res.render('index', { title: 'Express',data: d });
        });
    });
};
```

And for view this is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p> <%= data %> </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Problem is my console is printing out all the 50 results returned by google but its not showing in views. Whats the problem? And how to fix it?

Comment: The `data` event fires once for each chunk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you can use the `https` module to make requests, most people would use a nice 3rd-party library. The most popular is [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request). Another popular choice is [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent), which is written by the author of Express.

Since you’re new to Node.js, you should understand what’s happening and how to use the `https` module directly.

When you call `https.get()`, the `response` object that is returned to your callback is a **stream**.

Readable streams emit `'data'` events each time a chunk of data is received. The data may be broken into several chunks. You get one `'data'` event for each chunk. It’s up to you to assemble all the chunks together!

The stream will emit an `'end'` event when all the data has been received. That’s when you would process the data and render your template.

The chunks you get in each `'data'` event will be [`Buffer`s](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html). But if you call `response.setEncoding('utf8')`, that causes the chunks to be returned as strings instead.

You need to call `response.setEncoding()` **before** handling your first `'data'` event. (In your code, the first `'data'` event gets a `Buffer`, then you call `response.setEncoding()`, and any additional data events get strings.)

Here is how it looks:

```
https.get(url, function(response) {
    // each time we get a chunk, we will append it to this var
    var data = '';

    response.setEncoding('utf8');

    response.on('data', function(chunk) { data += chunk; });

    response.on('end', function() {
        // when we get the 'end' event we know all the data has
        // been received
        console.log(data);
        res.render('index', { title: 'Express', data: data });
    });
}).on('error', function(err) {
  // any error handling goes here
  console.error(err);
});
```

Does that seem like a lot of code? Here is the same handler using `request`. It’s much shorter:

```
request.get(url, function(err, resp, data) {
  if (err) { return console.error(err); }
  console.log(data);
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express', data: data });
});
```

And, since YouTube is returning JSON data, you can even have `request` parse the data into a JavaScript object. Just change the first argument as shown here:

```
request.get({url: url, json: true}, function(err, resp, data) {
    ...
});
```